# Teams proactive messages with uninstalled app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to build a personal Teams bot which has to send proactive messages regularly. I made it work by storing the conversation when the user installed the app, just like the [examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet). Now it works great, but I realized that I keep messaging users that have uninstalled my application. I can't seem to find any event that is triggered when a user uninstalls a personal scoped bot (app).

I tried [conversation events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=typescript), but nothing seems to be triggered for personal scoped bots at least.

I'm using the NodeJs botbuilder SDK.

Open to any suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no such event unfortunately. I think you'll just receive a 403 at the moment without much info. This is due to change though - Microsoft just made an announcement about this yesterday in fact. See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/best-practices-and-updates-for-bot-lifecycle-events-in-microsoft-teams/ in the paragraph "Changes to post uninstall behavior for bots in personal scope":

> Moving forward we’ll also align the post uninstall behavior for bots in the personal scope with the teams and groupChat scopes and you will not be able to send or receive messages after an app has been uninstalled. Your bot will receive a 403 response code to new messages posted by your bot. The 403 response code will have fields telling you the reason behind the it – which is either the app was uninstalled or the bot was blocked. We expect these changes to roll out in the coming few months.

Comment: @mihristov, Does the above resolution works for you? In addition you can try removing the conversation ID from the storage once the user uninstalls the bot.

Comment: @Saonti-MSFT not really. I accepted the answer just because it matched with my research. There are no events triggered by user uninstalling an app, so I can't really update my storage at the moment.

Comment: @mihristov As suggested above those changes will be coming up within months. Additionally if you have any other feature requests or ideas you can raise [Uservoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/)